# Is it possible to run mod_python Python Server Pages outside of the Apache server context?

Tags: python, apache, mod-python

I have experience coding PHP and Python but have until recently not used Python for much web development.

I have started a project using mod_python with Python Server Pages which does a very good job of what I need it to do. Amongst the advantages of this is performance; the web server does not spawn a new interpreter for each request.

The system will finally be deployed on a server where I am able to setup `/etc/apache/conf.d` correctly, etc.

However, during development and for automated regression testing I would like the ability to run the `.psp` scripts without having to serve using an Apache instance.  For example, it is possible to run PHP scripts using the PHP cli, and I would like to run my `.psp` scripts from the shell and see the resulting HTTP/HTML on stdout.

I suppose this mode would need to support simulation of POST requests, etc.

**Update**

OK, after typing all that question I discovered the `mod_python` command line in the manual:
http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/commandline.html

I guess that would get me most of the way there, which is to be able to exercise my application as a local user without deploying to an Apache server.

I am leaving this question here in case anyone does a web search like I did.

Comment: You could add your `update` as answer - and you could mark it as accepted, and we could upvote it.

Comment: Lols, I was in the middle of doing that when your comment appeared!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mod_python command line tool is one way to do this.

See http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/commandline.html

Essentially,

```
mod_python create /path/to/new/server_root \
--listen 8888 \
--pythonpath=/path/to/my/app \
--pythonhandler=mod_python.wsgi \
--pythonoption="mod_python.wsgi.application myapp.wsgi::application"
```

sets up a skeleton app.

Then you run it:

```
mod_python start /path/to/new/server_root/conf/httpd.conf

wget http://localhost/path/to/my/app:8888
```

I am still testing this...

**Caveat** This function only seems to be from 3.4.0

Comment: and Debian Wheezy defaults to 3.3.1... just my luck. Hopefully someone else gets to test this by the time I get around to building a VM with a later version

Comment: Here is when they added it: http://grisha.org/blog/2013/09/25/running-a-wsgi-app-on-apache-should-not-be-this-hard/

Comment: I installed apache mod_python on ubuntu but I dont have mod_python binary to run it outside of the apache. How can I get that?